# Eclipse plugin - How to inject a IWorkbenchWindow in the constructor of a command handler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to test a command handler class of my Eclipse plugin. That's why I want to inject an instance of IWorkbenchWindow in the constructor of this handler class, because

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
```

leaves me with a dependency on PlatformUI.

However I tried to do this

```
@Inject
public FindAndReplaceHandler(IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow) {
    this.fWorkbenchWindow = workbenchWindow;
```

and then the framework throws an NoSuchMethodException complaining that the FindAndReplaceHandler class hasn't got a no-argument constructor.

My class FindAndReplaceHandler extends AbstractHandler and overrides

```
void execute(ExecutionEvent event)
```

(So I don't use the modern way with the annotations @Execute and @CanExecute)

My version of Eclipse is: Version: Mars.2 (4.5.2).
I created my Eclipse plugin project with the setting Eclipse version = "3.5 or greater". However maybe I need to have the e4 tools installed and work with them? How to install them?

Any ideas how I can solve this problem are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @Inject style of command handler is only used when writing pure e4 style plugins (and these don't use `IWorkbenchWindow` or `PlatformUI`).

If you want to use `IWorkbenchWindow` you are writing a 3.x compatibility mode plugin and can't use injection for the command handler (and most other things). You must have a no arguments constructor for the command handler.